# Decouple user information and authentication information in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

First off, I am new to Symfony, so I don't know the exact functionality of bundles like `FOSUserBundle` etc., as well as the terminology.

---

I am looking for a way to use the Symfony security component in a way that enables me to decouple a user's login credentials (say, a login name and a password, maybe the roles) from the actual user meta data (like first name, last name, groups, birth date, etc.).

The idea is that a user can login with different sets of login name/password and still be recognized as the same user (in the end that means, getting the same `User` object).

To me, this comes especially handy in combination with multiple authentication providers. For example, if I wanted to enable my users to login via an OAuth2 service *as an alternative* to logging in with their locally-hosted login name/password-combination (like StackExchange does, for instance), how would I do that?

---

I have read multiple pages of documentation of Symfony, e.g.:

- https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html
- https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html#create-your-user-entity

This latter one even says at `1) Create your User Entity`, that a `password` is a field of `User`.

Comment: Create 2 models like `User` and `UserCredentials`, with 1-to-many relation. Use `User` to keep your metadata, and `UserCredentials` for authentication.

Comment: That's actually what I did before porting to Symfony. The problem I see here is that `Controller::getUser()` would return an instance of `UserCredentials` then, likely leading to confusion since the function name is `getUser`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently created just that, first I named my classes UserCredentials and UserDitails and because of the confusion of the getUser function i decided to rename UserCredentials to User. I agree with Alex Blex about the relation (manyToOne on the User side). When you decouple your login and metadata you will need to learn how to embed forms or creating your own form models, which is something I am currently working on and you might need to implement callback functions for deleting and updating entities. The more I work on my UserBundle, the more it looks like the FOSUserBundle. There is quite a bit of work of designing it to work well but it's great for learning. If you wish to inspect how the FOSUserBundle works, after you install it, you can find it in the vendor/friendsOfSymfony folder, it might provide a few answers.

Comment: I'm probably gonna do it like this, although I hoped for there to be cleaner solution. Would you suggest outsourcing my business logic into a dedicated bundle?

Comment: Yes sure, no need to go to far though, if something is just not showing an elegant way to separate from other things and is simpler to just bundle up together go for it. With user accounts it's as clear as day